# Как удалить &nbsp; из строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

при парсинге [авито](https://www.avito.ru/) хотел вытащить цену которая лежит в class="price-text-_WjC0 но она имеет такой вид [image: введите сюда описание изображения] задача отсоединить число которое здесь должно быть 36 790 и знак рубля ₽ при этом стрипнуть все невидимые знаки &_nbsp;

```
for i in get_all_price:
        text_get_all_price = i.text
        text_get_all_price_strip = text_get_all_price.strip('&nbsp;')
```

при принте в консоль выходит значения не стрипнутое

на 20 000 видно что есть пробел , а надо что бы цифра выглядела таким образом 20000 что бы в последствии провести проверку isdigit()

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&nbsp;` - это последовательность для XML/HTML, а в коде питона это символ `\xa0`

Кроме того, `str.strip` удаляет символы слева и справа, а не внутри. Вам нужно использовать `str.replace`:

```
text_get_all_price_strip = text_get_all_price_strip.replace('\xa0', '')
```

---

**PS.**

Возможно, вам имеет смысл вообще удалять все символы кроме цифр, запятой и точки

Пример:

```
import re

price = '10 \xa0 000₽'
print(price)
price = re.sub(r'[^\d,.]', '', price)
print(price)
```

Результат:

```
10   000₽
10000
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def clear_string(val: str):
    if isinstance(val, str):
        from unicodedata import normalize, is_normalized
        if not is_normalized('NFKC', val):
            return normalize('NFKC', val)
    return val
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]